# how do I align an image between text?

Tags: html, css

So I've been working on a page with text and an image. However, I can't find a way to put the image between the text. either it stays on the top left, or it only centers horizontally. here is the code that is of importance:

```
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
background-image: url("rainbowbg.png");
}
div #hype {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
positon: relative;
}
#hypetop {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#hypebot {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.hypetext {
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
font-size: 64px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class="hypetext" id="hypetop">DIRE</h1>
<img id="hype" src="DIREHYPE.png" width="224" height="224">
<h1 class="hypetext" id="hypebot">HYPPPPPPPPPPPE</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

If anyone knows how I could get the image centered between the text, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this responsive css code. It may be help for you. Try it.I can change only `position:fixed` to `position:relative`.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/z9szfum3/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
<h1 class="hypetext" id="hypetop">DIRE</h1>
    <img id="hype" src="http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png" width="224" height="224"/>
<h1 class="hypetext" id="hypebot">HYPPPPPPPPPPPE</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
body {
margin: 0;
background-image: url("rainbowbg.png");
}
div #hype {
margin:auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin-top:50px;
}
#hypetop {
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#hypebot {
position:relative;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.hypetext {
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
font-size: 64px;
text-align: center;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

you have to imagine them as blocks first. From what I get .. you need 3 blocks in the horizontal order: paragraph | image | paragraph , which gives us the following structure:

```
<p></p><img></img><p></p>
```

what you are missing is.. that you need to use the span tag instead fo a  tag to make them not break. Which is opposite of making the page responsive (using )

simply put them like this:

```html
<span>
<span id="test"><h1></h1></span>
<img src="" width="200px" height="200px" />
<span id="test"><h1></h1></span>
</span>
```

```css
 #test {
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 }
```

giving the above css rules... puts the text into a invisible/transparent block.. because we are not declaring any backround-color value. thus all 3 blocks become equal size.. 200px by 200px .. side-by-side in one line..

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:fixed; from hypetop and hypebot. This caused these elements to have fixed positions and not relative to the image.